# grails fields plugin <f:display is 'chopping off' bootstrap dropright action with a table of values

Tags: grails, plugins, bootstrap-4, field

grails v 3.3.9, fields plugin

fighting with fields plgin and theres a problem when rendering domain objects and using bootstrap

i've got a sample here from a simple standalone page to show the problem

```
<p>f:display category </p>
<f:display bean="maintenanceAgreement" >

</f:display>

<hr />

<p>f:field category</p>
<f:field bean="${this.pageScope.maintenanceAgreement}" property="category">
    <g:render template="/_fields/map/displayWidget" ></g:render>
    </f:field>

<hr />
```

in essenence i have added a template in "/_fields/map/displayWidget" that renders a drop right table on a button

when you render a map field directly from your Domain object the sample table opens and you get all of the table

however when you

you can see the differences between using f.display (has clipping problem), f.field ( which seems to work) and f.all that ignores my _fields/map/_displayWidget.gsp

I dont want to have not use the fields plugin but its not working with bootstrap templating

has any one come up with a fix for this problem?

the project demo page is here 
[github standalone page to show rendering problem](https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app/blob/master/grails-app/views/maintenanceAgreement/plain2.gsp)

the attached shows the output as you try each and select category property

[image]

Comment: also worth noting (that you cant really see it on the above, is that that F:display rendered  drop down also clips the top shadow round the button, the left, bottom and right hand side render shadow ok - but the top is not there, and the table of course is clipped and doesn't render correctly

Answer (score 0):

well goldarn it another 2 days down the pan - but i have it !

I thought at first it was something to do with fields plugin processing.  so i hacked a clone of plugin project locally and added some bits so i could watch it/debug step through it

in doing so i noted that my dummy web domain class page i'd cut across to the plugin didnt have the clipping problem.  but the styles were not the same so i copied main.css and grails.css from ordinary project back into the plugin, then re rendered in the browser -  and the clipping happened again.

so its in the css!.  some very careful watching of browser and looking at the browser 'inspect' indicated that the clipping seemed to be enabled very early on in the journey.

so in my dummy page i just used

I then spent a day wandering round the various bits of fields plugin as its not that well explained anywhere.

if you look at the plugins taglib display method, by default that triggers the /templates/fields/_list.gsp.  naming is a little odd but its the gsp that renders the domains persistent attributes as an ordered list - the plugins default _list.gsp looks like this

```
<ol class="property-list ${domainClass.decapitalizedName}">
    <g:each in="${domainProperties}" var="p">
        <li class="fieldcontain">
            <span id="${p.name}-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="${domainClass.decapitalizedName}.${p.name}.label" default="${p.defaultLabel}" /></span>
            <div class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${p.name}-label">${body(p)}</div>
        </li>
    </g:each>
</ol>
```

so after much exploration coming up through templates, from the bottom  I ended up right at the top with the '

so nearly there now.  back into main.css that i'd copied in.  if you edit that, down around line 215 you get this style.  If you comment out the overflow property - its all fixed !

```
.property-list .fieldcontain {
    list-style: none;
    /*overflow: hidden; */

    zoom: 1;
}
```

I tried auto, scroll, and visible but that seems to much about with too much of the page so best to just comment it out.

once you do that - the rest of the rendering of your forms starts to work !! blimey one line of css for all that pain.  Attached is the page using

[image]

Lastly through out all this, id ended up digging through /tracing fields plugin.  What a nest that is.  Not really finished here, but basically

with no body just renders a label and no content.  So you either need to provide provide a body tag, say  to get the value field displayed.

as

if no widget template has been defined then the renderDefaultDisplay is called which again has very limited options for controlling the rendering by falling through a 'switch (prop.type)' and basically calls either g.format (bool), g.formatDate (but no LocalDateTime/LocalDate Support) or g.fieldValue, non of which are bootstrap enabled.

if you call

these two diagrams are not beautiful but just high level pseudo code walk through for what the core tags are trying to do.  One day i'll try and pretty that up but it might help you if you get stuck

I'll raise a bug for the main.css clipping directly to the grails team and see what happens, but you can comment the line out yourself if you fall foul of it.

[image]

[image]